# Ограничения вывода имени из БД

Tags: php, mysqli

Подскажите как нажатием кнопки выводить имя из базы данных один раз, 
проблема в том что я вывожу имя но при втором ножати он опять выводит , нужно поставить ограничения на вывод из БД
кнопка сделано на html  методом POST,

пример:

```
    require_once('process.php');  //---Mysqli connect DB

//Кнопка
    <form name="frm" method="POST">
               <button  name="singline"  value="wcenter">Очередь</button>
    </form>

//Добавления в базу 
    if(isset($_POST['singline'])) {
        $query="INSERT INTO `online`(`id`, `onusername`, `onsurname`, `date`) VALUES 
        (NULL, '$personal', '$sur', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
        $result=$con->query($query);  
        mysqli_clode();
    }
  //Вывод массива в БД  
    $select=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id`, `onusername`, `onsurname`, `date` FROM `online`;");
    while ($m=mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
        $monitor1=$m['onusername']." ";
        $monitor2=$m['onsurname']." ";
        $monitor="$monitor1, $monitor2";
        echo ($monitor. "<br>");
    }
```

Comment: $select=mysqli_query
($con, "SELECT `id`, `onusername`, `onsurname`, `date` FROM `online`;");

while ($m=mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
    $monitor1=$m['onusername']." ";
    $monitor2=$m['onsurname']." ";
    $monitor="$monitor1, $monitor2";
    echo ($monitor. "<br>");
}

Comment: У меня при нажатии кнопки выводиться Имя и Фамилия, при повторной нажатии надо чтоб кнопка не реагировала или сообщение выводило

Comment: Понимаете ли, сегодня суббота, телепатический и предсказательные модули на зарядке. Вам просто физически не смогут дать ответ, почему кнопка работает неверно, если вы не покажете код работы этой кнопки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы кнопка сработала один раз можно сделать так:

```js
/* Флаг, отвечающий за вызов функции */
 
let RUN = true;
  
$('button[name="my"]').on('click', function(){
  if ( RUN ) {
    $( this ).text('Нажимать бесполезно');
    $( this ).after('<div class="alert alert-primary mr-3 ml-3" role="alert">Иванов Иван Иванович</div>');
    RUN = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-3" name="my">Можно выводить</button>
```

Можно сделать так:

```js
$('button[name="my"]').on('click', function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-3" name="my">Можно выводить</button>
```

А можно быть сатанистом мазохистам и через `ajax` в бд изменять флаг на вывод данных из бд.

Comment: Судя по коду автора там не запрос к API, а явная перерисовка страницы.

Comment: @rjhdby В вопросе это не указано явно. Возможно, мой ответ и не в кассу, а возможно и в.

Comment: Ну вот скажите, как можно иначе интерпретировать `echo ($monitor. "<br>");` в цикле? :)

Comment: Конкретнее это страница для  туалета в очереди ,   оператор заходит по логину и пароли SESSION, посла открывается другая  страница, там 3 кнопки, Кнопка1- Войти в очередь, Кнопка2- Выйти в WC, Кнопка3- Выйти из WC и очереди

Comment: Сейчас речь идет о 1 кнопке, Войти в очередь, но когда нажимаю второй раз на 1кнопку он опять добавляется в базу

Answer (score 0):

Все логично, сколько раз вы принимаете `$_POST['singline']` - столько записей в БД и добавится. А ваш селект читает вообще все записи из БД и в цикле их выводит.

В зависимости от того, что вам действительно нужно, есть несколько вариантов.

Для начала я бы изменил структуру таблицы и сделал поле `id` автоинкрементным и первичным ключом.

1) Вам нужно хранить в БД все факты нажатия кнопки, а выводить последнюю для всех пользователей.

`SELECT onusername, onsurname, MAX(date) FROM online GROUP BY onusername, onsurname;`

2) Вам нужно хранить только факт последнего нажатия кнопки

Самый дурацкий вариант - сделать первичный ключ на поля (onusername, onsurname). Правильный вариант с `id` - но это теории на целую статью будет - потом сами разберетесь.

Обновляем значение (Запомните - подставлять переменные напрямую в запрос - это очень плохо! Почитайте про подготовленные запросы):

```
INSERT INTO online (onusername, onsurname, date) 
VALUES ('$personal', '$sur', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date=UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Читаем так-же, как у вас в коде.